# How to preserve function overloads when mapping over a Typescript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading, mapped-types, keyof

## Code

Imagine an interface with two function overloads.

```
interface Api {
  parseNumber(input: string, useBigInt: true): bigint
  parseNumber(input: string, useBigInt: false): number
}
```

How can you map over these functions to create a new interface with async versions of each function?

```
{
  parseNumber(input: string, useBigInt: true): Promise<bigint>
  parseNumber(input: string, useBigInt: false): Promise<number>
}
```

## What I tried

You can easily pull out a union of function names, a union of the function signatures, but when you ask for a union of the return types you only get the last one in declaration order.

```
type TMethodNames = keyof Api; // GOOD: `parseNumber`
type TMethodImplementations = Api[keyof Api]; // GOOD: both signatures
type TMethodReturns = ReturnType<TMethodImplementations> // BAD: only `number` rather than `number | bigint`
```

Trying to produce a new interface via mapping results in all but the last function signature being dropped.

```
type AsyncApi = {
  [TMethodName in keyof Api]: (...args: Parameters<Api[TMethodName]>) => Promise<ReturnType<Api[TMethodName]>>
};

const asyncApi = null as unknown as AsyncApi;
asyncApi.parseNumber('123', false); // GOOD: return type is `Promise<number>`
asyncApi.parseNumber('123', true); // BAD: signature is completely missing
```

Comment: It's unfortunately a missing feature; see [ms/TS#29732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732) and the answers to the linked questions for possible approaches; nothing great here, though.

Comment: Noooooooo! Ugh. I need this badly, to be able to finish up an API I'm working on. :(